# How do I generate the variation file for all assets

Tags: assets, akeneo

I'm new to Akeneo, and I discovered profile configuration for assets.

So I imported my YML in order to add asset transformations, and now, cli based, I can't find a command that allows me to generate the variation file for all assets. I saw the command to do that asset by asset and channel by channel, but I need to do that for all of them.

Do you know how I can manage to do that ? I already tried `pim:asset:generate-missing-variation-files` but that didn't change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **no built-in command** to do that, however you could develop a very simple command to achieve this.

You can use the `pimee_product_asset.finder.asset` service to call `retrieveVariationsNotGenerated()` in order to retrieve every variation that are not yet genreated, then finally use the `pimee_product_asset.variation_file_generator` to generate the variation with `generate()`.

Not tested code, but this would be like that:

```
$finder = $this->get('pimee_product_asset.finder.asset');
$generator = $this->get('pimee_product_asset.variation_file_generator');

$variations = $finder->retrieveVariationsNotGenerated();
foreach ($variations as $variation) {
    $generator->generate($variation);
}
```